# Git: Missing files after modified push request

Tags: git, github

I forked a repository from github, did a few changes and pushed them back to my github repository. I did a pull request and was told to change a few things. So I changed a few things, committed them and did a git push.

Problem is, the files werent added to my repository and instead the state of my repository was revoked to the state before my last changes. I cant find my changes in the history as well. Is there any chance I can save my work or do I have to do it again?

Comment: I am having same issue. Where did you find your pushed files?

Comment: no, luckily i didnt change a lot so i could recreate all changes rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your new commit in Github?
Do you see them locally?
Have you pushed to another repo instead of your Github's one? A different branch?

Try looking at http://github.com/your_user/your_repo/network to see commits in chronological order. Maybe they're there in another branch.